# Jenkins use maven release without ssh and git installed

Tags: java, git, docker, maven, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and Maven Release plugin to make the release to tag to a private owned GitLab using a SSH private key, in an isolated docker image:

```
withDockerContainer(image: 'maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8') {
    sshagent (credentials: ["${GITLAB_CREDS}"]) {
        sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@gitlab.***.com'
        sh 'git config --global user.email "no-one@noemail.com"'
        sh 'git config --global user.name "Jenkins Job"'
        sh "mvn -B clean release:prepare release:perform -q"
    }
}
```

This works fine until SysAdmin team decided to run Jenkins using user jenkins:jenkins which maven docker doesn't have but, ssh requires a valid user. And it throws error:

```
No user exists for uid 332
```

So I don't want it to rely on system's native git client but a maven impl. After some investigation, seems maven-scm-provider-jgit is what I need. So I configured it in pom followed by the instruction in its website:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
            <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
            <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And in settings.xml:

```
<server>
    <id>git@gitlab.***.com</id>
    <privateKey>${ssh.privateKey}</privateKey>
    <passphrase></passphrase>
</server>
```

And then in script:

```
withDockerContainer(image: 'maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8-slim') {
    withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "${GITLAB_CREDS}", keyFileVariable: 'keyFile')]) {
        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'maven-nexus-settings', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
             sh "mvn -B -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS} clean release:prepare release:perform -Dssh.privateKey=${keyFile} -q"
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns error:

- mvn -B -s /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-test@tmp/config6359189442870799267tmp clean release:prepare release:perform -Dssh.privateKey=**** -q
  The authenticity of host 'gitlab.host.com' cannot be established.: The EC key's fingerprints are:: MD5:7b:b2:aa:81:25:b9:88:6f:62:4c:13:d4:87:f9:c5:b5: SHA256:PYlJZompVha0FYBp5bTVR56HdGw3ZtfFkVhWol1OLgw: Accept and store this key, and continue connecting? (yes/no): [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0:prepare (default-cli) on project jenkins-test: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. JGit checkin failure! git@gitlab.host.com:dev-team/jenkins-test.git: DefaultAuthFuture[ssh-connection]: Failed (IllegalStateException) to execute: Cannot prompt user: Failed to read user response: EOF -> [Help 1]

Any suggestion on how to fix this error?

Comment: Error messages and logs have to use the same format as code, for readability.

Comment: @aled, I know, but it's one line and very long error, I tried using code format and it seems even worse so I didn't use it. Please understand.

Comment: On regards of the first failure, in custom Dockerfiles we use to create the Jenkins user for avoid such issue. Have you try it?

Comment: Yes, it should work with custom Docker images, but how to fix this using public images like 'maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8'